# How do I change a range of date in a column to a range of date of columns, with a value in the new column of which the range is true of

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 columns, Country, Reactor in use and Reactor not in use, i want to transform this dataset into one that has the columns; Country, and all the years all reactors have been in use. (for example if the earliest start is 1958, and the latest not in use is 2021, the Columns are Country, 1958, 1959, 1960 etc until 2021.
In the new columns i want a value (could be 1 or anything) of the range that was given from each country.

Original dataset = [Original dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePjbl.png)

Expected dataset = [Expected dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSKp4.png)

I don't know where to start, i have turned the values in the Reactor in use and Reactor not in use columns from object to int64. But now i am at a bottleneck.

Comment: Please avoid posting images and replace them with their content.

Comment: I copied the content and pasted it, but it gets transformed into images rather than cells. I'm sorry I'll try to do it correct next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create difference of years with repeat rows by [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) and [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) first, then all years by add counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to `Reactor not in use`, remove duplicates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and reshape by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df = df.reset_index(rop=True)

df1 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Reactor not in use'].sub(df['Reactor in use']).add(1))]

df1 = (df1.assign(year = df1['Reactor in use'].add(df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount()),
                  val = 1)
          .drop_duplicates(['Country','year'])
          .pivot(index='Country', columns='year', values='val'))
```